# How can i span my table cell to different rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, html-table

I'm trying to implement this table that has the table header on the left side of the table, and the cell with the label header spans to multiple rows as long as the data label falls under the same header. Here's my very noob implementation...

```
labels.map((label, index) => (
            <>
              <tr key={index}>
                {data.map((row, ndx) => {
                  return row.rowLabel === label ? (
                    <>
                      <tr
                        key={ndx}
                        style={{
                          display: 'flex',
                          borderBottom: '1px solid #E1D9D6',
                        }}
                      >
                        <td
                          style={{
                            width: '33%',
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            borderRight: '1px solid #E1D9D6',
                            fontSize: '9px',
                          }}
                          id='label'
                        >
                          {label}
                        </td>
                        <div
                          style={{
                            borderBottom: '1px solid #E1D9D6',
                          }}
                        >
                          <td
                            style={{
                              width: '50%',
                              paddingLeft: '5px',
                              fontSize: '9px',
                            }}
                          >
                            {row.key}
                          </td>
                          <td
                            style={{
                              borderLeft: '1px solid #E1D9D6',
                              width: '50%',
                              textAlign: 'right',
                              fontSize: '9px',
                              paddingRight: '5px',
                            }}
                          >
                            {row.value}
                          </td>
                        </div>
                      </tr>
                    </>
                  ) : null;
                })}
              </tr>
            </>
          ))
```

What im expecting...

```
_______________
| LABEL 1 | 1 |
|_________|___| 
|         | 2 |
|         |___|
| LABEL 2 |   | 
|_________|_3_|
```

what i currently have...

```
_______________
| LABEL 1 | 1 |
|_________|___|
| LABEL 2 | 2 |
|_________|___|
| LABEL 2 | 3 |
|_________|___|
```

As of now, the header label appears on each row that gets mapped out.

I'd be very grateful for help on this. I'm a noob, and desperate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, count the number of duplicate labels and use shouldMerge within the data.map function to check if the previous row has the same rowLabel. If so, use rowSpan to span across rows.

Sample code

```
// Count the number of rows for each label
const numRowsByLabel = data.reduce((acc, row) => {
  const label = row.rowLabel;
  acc[label] = (acc[label] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

return (
  <tbody>
    {labels.map((label, index) => {
      // Initialize the flag to indicate the first row for this label
      let isFirstRow = true;
      return data.map((row, ndx) => {
        if (row.rowLabel !== label) {
          return null;
        }
        // Get the number of rows for this label
        const numRows = numRowsByLabel[label];

        // Determine whether to merge cells with the previous row
        const shouldMerge = !isFirstRow && ndx > 0 && data[ndx - 1].rowLabel === label;
        isFirstRow = false;

        return (
          <tr key={`${label}-${ndx}`}>
            {shouldMerge ? null : (
              <td
                rowSpan={numRows}
                style={{ ...
                }}
                id='label'
              >
                {label}
              </td>
            )}
            <td
              style={{...
              }}
            >
              {row.key}
            </td>
            <td
              style={{...
              }}
            >
              {row.value}
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      });
    })}
  </tbody>
);
```